# Registration and Unregistration of custom generated panels isn't working

Tags: python, error, panel

I made this add-on script that creates panels for each node in the compositor when the button is pressed. However when I install the addon and remove or disable it only the panel with the button is removed as well but the panels created procedurally are still visible so somehow the registration and registration fails. I am pretty sure that the error is located in the list "classes" bc it's empty but when I don't define it in the registration function the error raises that the list "classes" isn't defined so what to do? You should be able to recreate the problem by installing the code as an addon and then pressing the button in the compositor (if "use nodes" is enabled) to spawn the panels and then remove the addon the panels will stay. So my question is how can I register and unregister the generated panels properly? Since I am a beginner a detailed code on what's missing would be really awesome! Thank you!

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Test",
    "author" : "Your Name", 
    "description" : "",
    "blender" : (3, 0, 0),
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "doc_url": "", 
    "tracker_url": "", 
    "category" : "3D View" 
}


import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews


addon_keymaps = {}
_icons = None
class SNA_OT_Operator_6Aa00(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sna.operator_6aa00"
    bl_label = "Operator"
    bl_description = ""
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        if bpy.app.version >= (3, 0, 0) and True:
            cls.poll_message_set('')
        return not False

    def execute(self, context):
        LISTINPUT = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes
        category = "TEST"
        classes = []

        def create_node_panel(node, order):
            class MyNodePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
                bl_label = f"{node.name}"
                bl_idname = f"NODE_PT_{node.name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_').replace('.', '_').replace('(', '_').replace(')', '').replace('/', '_')}"
                bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
                bl_region_type = 'UI'
                bl_category = category
                bl_order = order

                @classmethod
                def poll(cls, context):
                    return context.space_data.tree_type == 'CompositorNodeTree'

                def draw(self, context):
                    layout = self.layout
                    if node is None:
                        layout.label(text="Node not found")
                        return
                    inputs = [input for input in node.inputs if input.enabled and not input.hide_value and not input.is_linked]
                    box = layout.box()
                    for input in inputs:
                        box.prop(node.inputs[input.name], "default_value", text=input.name)
                    if "OBJSpecific" in self.bl_label:
                        sub_box = box.box()
                        row = sub_box.row()
                        row.alignment = 'CENTER'
                        row.scale_x = 1
                        row.scale_y = 1
                        row.label(text='Pointerobject', icon_value=78 )
                        sub_box.prop(bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].node_tree.nodes[node.name].node_tree, 'sna_pointerobjmask',text='')
                        sub_box.operator('sna.clearpasses_fe83e', text='Clear All Passes', icon_value=3, emboss=True, depress=False)
            return MyNodePanel
        nodes = LISTINPUT
        order = 4
        for node in nodes:
            panel_class = create_node_panel(node, order)
            bpy.utils.register_class(panel_class)
            classes.append(panel_class)
            order += 1
        return {"FINISHED"}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return self.execute(context)


class SNA_PT_NEW_PANEL_943F3(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = 'New Panel'
    bl_idname = 'SNA_PT_NEW_PANEL_943F3'
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = ''
    bl_category = 'TEST'
    bl_order = 0
    bl_ui_units_x=0

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return not (False)

    def draw_header(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        op = layout.operator('sna.operator_6aa00', text='My Button', icon_value=0, emboss=True, depress=False)


def register():
    global _icons
    _icons = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    bpy.utils.register_class(SNA_OT_Operator_6Aa00)
    classes = []
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SNA_PT_NEW_PANEL_943F3)


def unregister():
    global _icons
    bpy.utils.previews.remove(_icons)
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps.values():
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SNA_OT_Operator_6Aa00)
    classes = []
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SNA_PT_NEW_PANEL_943F3)
```